# Redmine: How to move wiki pages to another project's wiki?

Tags: wiki, redmine

I have several wiki pages in a subproject B of my parent project A. Now I want to move them from B's wiki to A's wiki. How can I do this without copy-and-pasting all pages?

The guys at the Redmine forum suggest to edit the SQL database directly; there is also an open issue from other people with the same problem.
I looked at my mysql dump, but I didn't get exactly the place where to change the corresponding ids. Is the right place in table 'wiki_contents' or in 'wiki_content_versions' or anywhere else?

(Redmine 1.2.0 is used)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can move pages - I recommend making a backup before manipulating the db directly.

1. In the table `projects`, find the id's of project A and B.
2. In the table `wikis`, find the id's of the wikis corresponding to project A and B.
3. In the table `wiki_pages`, find the pages you'd like to move and simply change the `wiki_id`

Watch out for:

- *Page hierarchy* (`parent_id`): Not sure what happens if you move a page but you don't move its parent page. To be sure, you may want to set the value of `parent_id` to null and recreate the hierarchy once the page is moved.
- *User notifications*: I'm not sure what happens if a user watches a page which is moved to a project where the user doesn't have access anymore. To be sure you may want to delete some entries in the `watchers` table.
- *Wiki redirects*: When you rename a page, there is an option to redirect the old url to the new one. Those redirects are stored in `wiki_redirects` and may need to be moved to the new wiki, too.
- *Wiki links* in the content won't work anymore if the page linked to has not been moved, too.

Comment: Watchers who can't see the new page should be excluded from notifications. Deleting the watcher records would also work.